# Почему лошадей "стреноживают"?

Tags: этимология

Стреножить лошадь - спутать передние ноги, чтобы она не могла далеко уйти. Но интересно было бы узнать происхождение этого слова. Мне тут слышится слово "три", но к чему оно?
В общем, заранее благодарен за ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Треножить буквально — делать четвероногую лошадь трехногой. Связывают ноги различно, но так, чтобы получить "устойчивую конструкцию".

Comment: Обычно это делают с передними ногами. Да, получается такая тренога.